# how to open nivo lightbox using javascript

Tags: jquery, plugins, nivo-slider

I'm using nivo lightbox jquery plugin and not able to figure how to open it using javascript call. I'm creating gallery of hidden images and that gallery need to open up when user clicks on a thumb image, which is not part of the gallery.

Please not lightbox works on clicking one of the images (when i don't hide those images), so there is no problem with code initializing the lightbox.

code I have so far:

```
function showPortfolio(){
    $("#slider1 a").nivoLightbox();
    //need code to now open the light box
}
```